How to calculate positions of circles within a bigger circle, where each inner circle touches the neighbors and the outer circle?
I am trying to solve the following problem:
Given any number n of inner circles (C1..n) with different known radii ri (e.g. Coins) in a specific order.
How to place them in an bigger outer circle C with an unknown radius R with the following conditions:

each inner circle is inside the outer circle
each inner circle touches the outer circle in exactly one point/tangent
each inner circle touches the two neighboring circles in exactly one point each (without overlapping).
there is no very small inner circle that can "hide" between to bigger inner circles
the order of the inner circles is given
the position of the first two inner circles can be defined as a starting point respecting the constraints, eg:

generic: center Pi(xci,yci), Radius: ri -> Ci: (xi-xci)2+(yi-yci)2=ri2
first center P1(0,0) -> C1: (x1)2+(y1)2=r12
second Center P2(r1+r2, 0) -> C2: (x2-(r1+r2))2+(y2)2=r22



The positions of the other circles (and the center-point and radius of the outer circle) should be calculated.
Similar to the picture in this question - although the different radii in the picture in his case were by mistake.
I know that the distance of the center points of the two neighboring inner circles is the sum of their radii, so I know the lengths of the edges of a polygon through the inner circle centers; I know the sum of the internal angles to be (n-2)*180°; but I do not know the individual angles. If the inner circles would have the same radius, things would be easy...
In my current Python implementation I am starting from a too big regular polygon (edge length = biggest diameter length) that defines the centerpoints and iteratively adapts the line lengths and angles, until I get almost there.
Current result of my Python implementation
I am wondering if there is a mathematical/geometrical approach to solve this besides creating equations for each circle and the tangents and trying to solve this equation system.
BTW: I am not a math expert and it's just out of curiosity so please forgive any incorrectness ;-)

If you haven't seen this term yet, you might enjoy looking into Apollonian circle packings.

Yes, thanks, I've seen that before and read and learned a lot - but obviously not enough ;-). Most problems I found were about packing problems or the Descartes' theorem. I did not find someone that "only" wants to align the circles in the way I described.
